# jquery dialog not appearing

Tags: jquery, html, dialog

My page is supposed to post a dialog stating a set of guidelines to be used. A php script identifies which one(s) and creates the div(s) accordingly.

Then I do a simple `$(document).ready( function() { $("#guidelines").dialog();})`

The inner text (TEXT HERE) appears as html for half a second then 'disappears'.

Using Firefox's Inspect Element 3D View I can see that the dialog is there, it has just become invisible (http://imgur.com/R5vx9 - guidelines dialog is in the outlined red box).

With the code below you can see that 'display:block' is set, and I've made sure to include the link to the css.

I checked if there were any conflicting css arguments withing different sheets but haven't found any so far.

Here is the html

```
<div aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="outline: 0px none; z-index: 1001; position: relative; height: auto; width: auto; top: 300px; left: 0px; display: block;" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
        <span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-id-1">Guidelines</span>
        <a role="button" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div scrollleft="0" scrolltop="0" style="width: auto; min-height: 20px; height: auto;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="guidelines">
        TEXT HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help on this?

Comment: maybe about z-index property,i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below :

```
$("#guidelines").dialog(
{
    autoOpen: true,
    show: "blind",
    hide: "explode",
    closeOnEscape: false,
    close : function()
    {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    },
    buttons:
    {
        "YES": function()
        {
            ajax_call(href);
        },
        "NO": function()
        {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" ).dialog('destroy').remove();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this made it appear, i've tested it out and it seems i just needed to have: show: "blind"

Comment: cant +1 yet sorry, I dont have enough reputation, accepted answer though

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that autoOpen property is set to 'true' by default but following code may help you

$('#guidelines').dialog('open');

Call it after initialization of dialog function